# How Hints in this question are understood?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, spoilers

In [Your favourite maths puzzles](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/566/17975) there are hints stated in a different format.
for example,
Hint: GUVF VF RDHVINYRAG GB GUR ENGVBANY PNFR 
Are these meaningful ? Then how to understand them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\Huge\href{http://rot13.com}{\textbf{ebg13}}$$

Comment: This appears within the question, too. Read it more carefully.

Answer (score 1):

It's [ROT13](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ROT13) though that is really not necessary as SE supports spoiler syntax like:

```
>! This is a hint
```

which results in

> This is a hint

Comment: >! but it doesn't work in comments.